# SharedPreferences for making favorit list in app

Tags: android, json

I need To implement Favorite list in My app . After 4 days in searching and question from other, I get I should use database for making favorite list (My program populate recyclerviews with json) .

Then save the json to database is worked and I can with pressing one click add json to database and show the favorite list with database data.

as I say earlier I save json to database for achieve favorite list .

Now I have one problem, how can I show is this row added to favorite list or no?
In other word I want show the solid heart icon, if that row added to favorite list and show the border heart icon, if that row not added to favorite list .

I think for this work I need use the `SharedPreferences`

> This is my PreferenceHelper class:

```
public class PreferenceHelper {

    private static final String NAME = "MY_PREFERENCES";
    public static final String MY_DATA = "myData";

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,false);
    }

    public void putBoolean(String key, boolean value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

> And This is my `onBindViewHolder` of `AdapterRecyclerQuestion`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.txtTitle.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
        holder.txtCntDown.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownCnt());
        holder.txtAuthorName.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorName());
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorPic()).into(holder.imgAuthorPic);
        holder.txtDate.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDate());

        PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(holder.itemView.getContext());

        boolean checked = preferenceHelper.getBoolean(preferenceHelper.MY_DATA);
        if(checked){
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
        }else {
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
        }


        //=============BTN DOWNLOAD CLICK LISTENER =========================
        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink()));

                request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                request.setDescription("در حال دانلود");
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownFileName());
                long enqueueId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });

        //============== IMG ADD TO FAVORITE CLICK LISTENER ======================
        holder.imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(context);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 boolean isClicked = preferenceHelper.getBoolean(preferenceHelper.MY_DATA);

                if (!isClicked) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "اضافه شد " + isClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
                    preferenceHelper.putBoolean(preferenceHelper.MY_DATA, true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "حذف شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
                    preferenceHelper.putBoolean(preferenceHelper.MY_DATA, false);
                }
//=========== Save to Database =================================================         
                /*QuestionDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new QuestionDatabaseAdapter(v.getContext());

                ModelQuestion question = new ModelQuestion();

           /*question.setQuestionTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                question.setQuestionDesc(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
                question.setQuestionDate(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDate());
                question.setQuestionAuthorName(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorName());
                question.setQuestionAuthorPic(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorPic());
                question.setQuestionDownLink(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink());

                databaseAdapter.saveQuestion(question);

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "اضافه شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);*/

//===================================================================


            }
        });
    }
```

This code can't work .

Comment: When you run your code, what happens? Is the heart symbol always showing or not showing at all?

Comment: according to click on the heart it different , for ex if i click on the bordered heart it change to solid heart and when i exit and back again to this activity all items in recyclerview have a solid heart and

Answer (score 0):

If you want implementing the favourite list. you should save all the data in the `SQLite` and you can save it to the backend also with the state that is it added to favourite or not.

 I implement this simple demo app.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Movie>movieList= new ArrayList<>();
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    for(int i=0;i<=20;i++){
        movieList.add(new Movie("Title"+i,false));
    }

    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList, MainActivity.this, new myClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Movie obj, int pos) {
            if (obj.isFav()){
                obj.setFav(false);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Here you can save this item's state to the preference or sqlite. 
            }else {
                obj.setFav(true);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  // Here you can save this item's state to the preference or sqlite. 
            }

        }
    });
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

}
```

Movie.java

```
/**
 * Created by droidwithme on 24/05/16.
 */
public class Movie {
    private String title;

    public boolean isFav() {
        return isFav;
    }

    public void setFav(boolean fav) {
        isFav = fav;
    }

    private boolean isFav;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String title, boolean flag) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isFav=flag;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }


    }
```

Adapter's code.

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Movie> moviesList;
private Context context;
myClickListner myClickListner;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView imgFav;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
       imgFav=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageFav);
    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList, AppCompatActivity activity,myClickListner listner) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.context=activity;
    this.myClickListner=listner;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.imgFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListner.onItemClick(movie,position);
        }
    });
    if (movie.isFav()){
        holder.imgFav.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redheart));
    }else {
        holder.imgFav.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whiteheart));
    }




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
}
```

Click Interface(that helps to detect clicks in the `MainActivity`
myClickListner.java

```
    public interface myClickListner {
   void onItemClick(Movie obj,int pos);
}
```

main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageFav"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/whiteheart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and the required dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: can you give movie model